# How can I get data like A-B but not contains B-A?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have data in a table that has recurring rows but in a different order (row1.column1.value = row2.column2.value and vice versa) for example:

```
1   A   B   
2   B   A   
3   B   C   
4   C   B       
5   A   C   
6   C   A
...
```

From this table I would like to get the data that is unique (meaning that there is no other row that has these 2 values together) such as this:

```
1   A   B
3   B   C
6   C   A
...
```

Can anybody help me with this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: are `A` `B` value of different columns or values in a single column?

Comment: Can you edit your question and add the expected output, its still not clear what you want?

Comment: You need a simple filter condition like `WHERE Col1 = 'A' AND Col2 = 'B'`

Comment: You need to ask a better question

Comment: I think the question is pretty obvious I just don't know how to do it

Comment: Actually it's not so obvious. For starters, your expected output does not match your sample data...

Comment: It's unclear which row should be output CA or AC ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `CASE` to fetch distinct combination and get respective minimum id and fetch only those records.

Something like this

```
SELECT T1.* 
FROM table1 T1
INNER JOIN 
(
SELECT MIN(ID) as ID, CASE WHEN Col1 > Col2 THEN CONCAT(Col1 ,Col2) ELSE CONCAT(Col2,Col1) END GRP
FROM table1
GROUP BY CASE WHEN Col1 > Col2 THEN CONCAT(Col1,Col2) ELSE CONCAT(Col2, Col1) END
) T2
ON T1.ID = T2.ID;
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/319e4/10)

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT
*
FROM
  table
WHERE
(col1, col2) IN (
    SELECT DISTINCT
        (
            CASE
            WHEN STRCMP(col1, col2) < 0 THEN
                col1
            ELSE
                col2
            END
        ) AS col1,
        (
            CASE
            WHEN STRCMP(col1, col2) < 0 THEN
                col2
            ELSE
                col1
            END
        ) AS col2
    FROM
        table
);
```

Comment: That looks like a *really* elaborate way to say `SELECT * FROM table where col1 < col2`.

Comment: this doesn't return  C-A if A-C combination does not exist so not really a complete answer I think